# page will keep getting 404 error with {%endfor%} but if removed will render but now posts will show

Tags: python, django, django-views

Hi i'm hoping i make sense here i was hoping someone can point out for me why {% endfor % causes a 404 error for me but when i remove it the page renders but no posts show
thank you in advance i've also attached screenshots

code for Views

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


posts = [
{

   'author':  'Joshua Harvey',
   'title':    'blog post',
   'content':   'first post test',
   'date':       'may 1st 2021',
   
},
{

   'author':  ' Deidre gibson',
   'title':    'blog post 2',
   'content':   'second post test',
   'date':       'may 2st 2021',
   
}


]



def myView(request):
    context = {
          'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'hello/home.html', context)
def about(request):
    return render(request, 'hello/about.html', {'title':about})
```

code for home.html

```
{% extends "hello/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
        <article class="media content-section">
                <article class="media content-section">
                    <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="article-metadata">
                        <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
                        <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
                    </div>
                    <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
          
             
          {% endblock content %}
```

when i enter {%endfor} above {% endblock content%} i get 404 error for webpage but i need {%endfor%} to end the block but if i remove it i dont see any post's whatsoever

Comment: Shown code has no `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.title }}
    {{ post.date_posted }}
   ... 
{% endfor %}
```

This should work.
You are using {{ endfor }} and yet you did not start with a for loop.

Comment: Thanks homie I'll keep you posted

Comment: Accept as correct answer if it sorted you.